# Magento: adding new custom attribute product into cart remove the other cart products

Tags: php, arrays, magento, product, cart

I have an issue by adding custom attribute product into cart remove the other already added cart items.
I have checked by applying base theme, disabling install module replace the fresh core files of code/core/mage/checkout directory but issue still existing.
Kindly help me to solve this issue thanks in advance

Comment: Might be worth getting this migrated to http://magento.stackexchange.com/

Comment: migrated on magento stack exchange